# Why is the "self" parameter passed when calling a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Solution:
    def cuttingRope(self,n):
        dp = [0] * (n + 1)
        dp[2] = 1
        dp[1] = 1
        for i in range(3, n + 1):
            for j in range(i):
                dp[i] = max(dp[i], max(dp[i - j] * j, (i - j) * j))
        return dp[n]


print(Solution.cuttingRope(Solution, 10))
```

In the print statement, the "self" parameter is designated as the class "Solution", I don't understand this very well, can you give me a simple explanation

Comment: Well, *you are passing that parameter*. What is there to explain? Nothing is done with `self`, so you could pass whatever you want, as long as you pass something, because it is a required positional parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the word 'self'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self)

Comment: That's a method, not just a function. This should have been covered by [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: If you create an instance of `Solution` and then call `cuttingRope` using that instance you do not need to pass `Solution` as `self`:

`sol = Solution();
print(sol.cuttingRope(10))`

Comment: When writing a class with a method (which is not designated as `@classmethod`), then you're supposed to use it like `s = Solution(); s.cuttingRope(10)`. If you don't need a class—and there doesn't appear to be any obvious reason here why you would—then just write it as a plain function instead…?!

Comment: Note: The ``class Solution:`` (anti-) pattern is expected by some coding challenge sites.